# Why is GCE image/instance group performing more slowly than a single instance?

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

1. I installed wordpress on a single instance. (NGINX, Wordpress & Redis). Then created an instance group for that single instance.
2. I made an image of that instance, then made an instance template. Then created an instance group for that single instance.

Both are using SSD, us-central1-c, n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.75 GB memory), load balancer, Google Cloud. Essentially, they have the same setup, except for the fact that one is built on a single instance, and the other I made from an image of that instance.

The one made from the image has a TTFB of about .7seconds to 1.2seconds
The one made just on the single instance has a TTFB of about .15 seconds to .49 seconds.

Does this mean I am setting up something incorrectly?  (also I tried this in two different ways, by installing Wordpress differently both times). Both times it performed more slowly.

Comment: You might get a general answer to this question, but adding some additional details like these would help get specific help for your problem: where is the load balancer located? how is it configured to balance loads between the sites? this is about Wordpress, right? do you have a separate database in each location, or just one that all the Wordpress instances use?

Comment: I rewrote the question to make it apples to apples now, except for the fact that one is based off an image and the other was installed directly onto the instance. (As for your questions: I think the database would be in all separate locations, this is Wordpress, load balancer doesn't say where it is located, load balancer is now configured the same for both sets.  I removed the multi-region to isolate the problem.)

Comment: The details make this much more answerable, but I don’t know the answer :-(. Adding load balancing would probably add some latency, but if it’s balancing between two VMs in the same zone, I wouldn’t expect the increase to be in the 100s of milliseconds.

Comment: So by the sound of it and just to clarify, you are using two separate load balancers, and for the instance groups, you are using both an unmanaged instance group (for the instance you are not using a template for), and a managed instance group for the one you are using a template for? As a troubleshooting step I would suggest running a top command in each instance and verifying the resources being consumed are identical.